# Rotation composition in $R^3$ and linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I'm trying to understand why the result of a composition of linear transformations (two rotations) it is different from mapping the base vectors from $R^3$ to $R^3$ twice.
I'll explain.
I have a mapping: ϕ that maps vectors in $R^3$ to $R^3$ as a linear combinations of the canonical base vectors (**e1**,**e2**,**e3**).
The transformation matrix associated with ϕ is the following:

\begin{bmatrix}\cos(a)&0&\sin(a)\\0&1&0\\-\sin(a)&0&\cos(a)\end{bmatrix}
That is the classic counterclockwise rotation with respect to the e2 axis.

Now I want to map the canonical base vectors (**e1**,**e2**,**e3**) using ϕ.

$ϕ(\mathbf{e1}) = \cos(a) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) - \sin(a) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a) \\ 0 \\ -\sin(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

$ϕ(\mathbf{e2}) = 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 1 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

$ϕ(\mathbf{e3}) = \sin(a) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + \cos(a) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a) \\ 0 \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

After that, I want to perform a counterclockwise rotation around the rotated base vector **e3** (e.g. ϕ(**e3**)).

To do this, i'm using this transformation matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}\cos(b)&-\sin(b)&0\\\sin(b)&\cos(b)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

And I map the "old" rotated basis onto the new basis using Ψ:

$Ψ(ϕ(\mathbf{e1})) = \cos(b) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a) \\ 0 \\ -\sin(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + \sin(b) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a) \\ 0 \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a)\cos(b) \\ \sin(b) \\ -\sin(a)\cos(b) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

$Ψ(ϕ(\mathbf{e2})) = -\sin(b) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a) \\ 0 \\ -\sin(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + \cos(b) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a) \\ 0 \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} -\cos(a)\sin(b) \\ \cos(b) \\ \sin(a)\sin(b) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

$Ψ(ϕ(\mathbf{e3})) = 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a) \\ 0 \\ -\sin(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 0 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) + 1 \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a) \\ 0 \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a) \\ 0 \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Assuming that what is written is true, now I have tried to do the verification, checking if the composition of the two rotations actually gives me the same result.

Therefore:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(b)&-\sin(b)&0\\\sin(b)&\cos(b)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}\cos(a)&0&\sin(a)\\0&1&0\\-\sin(a)&0&\cos(a)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(a)\cos(b)&-\sin(b)&\sin(a)\cos(b)\\\sin(b)\cos(a)&\cos(b)&\sin(a)\sin(b)\\-\sin(a)&0&\cos(a)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

If now I tried to make a linear mapping transforming the canonical basic vectors with this composition of rotations, I would find a different result from the one found before.

Therefore (calling τ this linear mapping):

τ(**e1**) = \cos(a)\cos(b) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + \sin(b)\cos(a) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ - \sin(a) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \cos(a)\cos(b) \\ \sin(b)\cos(a) \\ -\sin(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

τ(**e2**) = -\sin(b) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + \cos(b) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + 0 $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} -\sin(b) \\ \cos(b) \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

τ(**e3**) = \sin(a)\cos(b) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + \sin(a)\sin(b) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + \cos(a) $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \sin(a)\cos(b) \\ \sin(a)\sin(b) \\ \cos(a) \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Clearly:
Ψ(ϕ(**e1**)) ≠ τ(**e1**), Ψ(ϕ(**e2**)) ≠ τ(**e2**), Ψ(ϕ(**e3**)) ≠ τ(**e3**)

When instead I should have expected the same result...

I noticed that by reversing the order of the matrix product, I get the same result instead... I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\phi(e_1)=(\cos(a),0,-\sin(a))=\cos(a)e_1-\sin(a)e_3.$$Therefore\begin{align}\psi\bigl(\phi(e_1)\bigr)&=\psi\bigl(\cos(a)e_1-\sin(a)e_3\bigr)\\&=\cos(a)\psi(e_1)-\sin(a)\psi(e_3).\end{align}There is no reason for you to assume that this is equal to$$\cos(b)\phi(e_1)+\sin(b)\phi(e_2)+0\times\phi(e_3),$$which is what you did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but ψ(**e1**) is equals to cos(b) **e1** + sin(b) **e2** + 0 **e3** and ψ(**e3**) is equals to 0**e1** + 0**e2** + 1 **e3** (for the e3-axis counterclockwise rotation) or am I wrong?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Fixed, my mistake was to use the transformation matrix (counterclockwise rotation about **e3**) starting from the base vectors already rotated around **e2**. Obviously, by changing the basic vectors, the transformation matrix also changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are not applying a matrix correctly to find the image of a column vector. When you are computing $\Psi(\phi(\mathbf{e1}))$, you can only use the entries of $\Psi$ and of $\phi(\mathbf{e1})$; in stead you are also using $\phi(\mathbf{e2})$ and $\phi(\mathbf{e3})$, which cannot be right. Use the entries of $\phi(\mathbf{e1})$ as coefficients in forming a linear combination of the columns of $\Psi$, not the entries of (just) one column of $\Psi$ as linear combination of things that make no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Anyway, what I did was 1) I map (through ϕ ) the three canonical versors as a linear combination of the same (counterclockwise rotation with respect to **e2**) 2) I map (through Ψ ) the three vectors I found from the previous mapping as a linear combination of the same (counter-clockwise rotation with respect to ϕ(**e3**), not **e3**, this is my mistake!). I gave myself an example and with 90 degree angles it actually produces the expected results.

Comment: @user3254491 When doing an algebraic computation, the geometric description of what you are doing should not matter a lot. What you call "map through $\Psi$ the three vectors" is just multiplying the matrix $\Psi$ with each of the three vectors individually. I don't know what you mean with "as a linear combination of the same" suggest you may be confused; each of the three vectors is mapped completely independently of the other ones; forming linear combinations of those three vectors is not at all what this is about. Whether a wrong approach works well for a special case does not matter.